# how to generate dynamic data for an item in listview

Tags: android, listview, listadapter

I have created a list activity calles as Category List to show a list of category dynamically from web by parsing an XML file. The XML file contains values "ID"(id of the particular category) and "title"(category name). So what I've done is, I've parsed the XML file and collected the ID and title to an ArrayList called categries using SAX parser.

In the list activity, I have a created a new string array and added the title of each category to it. The thing I want to do is to assign the category id to each category shown in the list view and to use the id to get the appropriate view for that category. Is there any way to assign an id to the each of the list items.

regards
dj

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492513

Comment: Hi  Marcel Gheorghita, Thanks for ur help! The link is good but in my case, I m not saving the data to the sqlite database. I want to generate another XML file from web based on the ID of category clicked  and to show the data based on that.

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a JavaBean, and fill it:

```
class YourBean {
  private int id;
  private String title;
  // add get / set methods
}
```

Create the list and put it in a ArrayList ,then fill a `Adapter` with it.

Then, you can use an http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html and in your `onClicked` etc method use `mAdapter.getItem(int)`. That's in very short words.

Take a look in the SDK examples.